# Module not found error in Python script running as a Windows Service

Tags: python-3.x, django, windows-services, waitress, servicemanager

I have a Django "learning project" which hosts a very simple web site, with `waitress` providing the WSGI server.  The project performs as expected when I execute the calling script from the command line.

From here I'm trying to set up the scaffolding to have it run as a Windows Service.  I installed `pywin32` and `servicemanager` to my virtual environment, and -- later on, trying to resolve an error -- also installed them to my "real" Python instance on the machine.  Despite this, I keep getting a `ModuleNotFoundError` error, citing `servicemanager`, when I try to start the created service:

[image: service start error]

This is the Python script I'm using; it is based on a template script I found [here](https://www.programming-books.io/essential/python/a-python-script-that-can-be-run-as-a-service-81a02f06a35141a1bc12d24f2f0f6243).

```
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import socket
from waitress import serve
from django_project.wsgi import application

class AppServerSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "PagesService"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Pages Service"

    def __init__(self,args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                              (self._svc_name_,''))
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        serve(application, port='8000')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

As noted above I've installed `servicemanager` to both the virtual environment and the "real" environment, I've followed the classic Roy request and rebooted the machine just to be sure. Here's the requirements.txt file I get from `pip freeze`, it shows `servicemanager` is there:

```
argcomplete==1.12.3
asgiref==3.6.0
atomicwrites==1.4.1
attrs==23.1.0
bottle==0.12.18
certifi==2022.12.7
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.4.6
Django==4.1.8
idna==2.10
more-itertools==9.1.0
mssql-django==1.2
packaging==23.1
pluggy==0.13.1
prettytable==0.7.2
py==1.11.0
PyHamcrest==2.0.2
pymongo==3.11.0
pyodbc==4.0.39
pytest==5.4.3
pytz==2023.3
pywin32==306
requests==2.24.0
servicemanager==2.0.10
sqlparse==0.4.4
tzdata==2023.3
urllib3==1.25.11
waitress==2.1.2
wcwidth==0.2.6
```

So I can't understand why the `servicemanager` module wouldn't be found or what else I could do to make it available.

Comment: Have you tried to print the current python interpreter, to make sure it is pointing to an interpreter with the correct packages?

Comment: The VM where I'm doing my development work has only one instance of Python, v3.11.3.  It's installed to C:\Program Files\Python311.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few more tests (read: shots in the dark) and doing some more extensive digging in Google with the resulting errors, I found [this article on Github](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1987).

The poster's issue was very similar, just with a different specific error.  Owing to circumstances, the poster was able to pin it down to an incompatibility between `pywin32` and Python 3.11 (since the issue started only when they upgraded from 3.10 to 3.11).  The clincher was that the issue went away when they reverted to 3.10.  ***(UPDATE, 2023-10-19: Issue is also triggered when using Python 3.12.)***

So I rebuilt my environment with the current 3.10 release (3.10.11), installed and ran the service -- and now it works.

[image: successful start]

Comment: I have same problem, but I need to keep with 3.11 version to run my app. So, can I install 3.10 just to install the service and keep with my app running on 3.11? I'm a bit confuse with that different envs

Comment: @PabloNascimento -- the problem occurs when starting the service, not when installing it.  If the current environment is 3.11 then the Windows service does not run.  *However*, looking back at the Github thread, I see another comment that might help you.  Another user said the problem does not occur if you can use Windows 11.  (I am not able to verify this myself, I don't have a machine with Windows 11 yet.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case is that I installed the modules via pip install. The user id didn't have write permission to the main installation of Python that I was using so it installed the modules in AppData under my username. When the Python script ran as a service, the account it was running under couldn't see the modules in my AppData.

Comment: That's a useful insight.  Could you expand on it with a few details?  Like, did the module-not-found error specifically come up in the context of the OP?  (When attempting to start a service.)  More importantly, what specific actions did you take after troubleshooting to resolve the error?  (Covering aspects like this will make your answer a good one and get it upvoted.)